# Google apps script project, associated sheets and the cloud project settings all disappeared

Tags: google-apps-script

So I just noticed that one of my app scripts projects is just gone. The script ran about 40 mins back - I can see it's log entries and in executions. But a few minutes later it all vanished. When I try to access the scripts project, I get - "Make sure that you have the correct URL and the file exists". Even a sheet associated with the project is gone and also the project disappeared from the GCP console. It almost looks this entire project got deleted - however none of these files are in the trash nor have they been scheduled for deletion.

Any help on this front would be really appreciated.

Comment: If the account is a GSuite account, you could contact customer service.  You can also contact Google Drive Support:  [Link to Google Drive Support](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/4431192?hl=en&ref_topic=14951)

Comment: I reported a problem with script.google.com to G Suite support and first they referred me to Google Play Developers :S. Then I made a post on the Google Apps Script community and on the Issue Tracker. Details on https://plus.google.com/u/0/106510732909452072295/posts/1aM7iaLQNje.